# Views SlidingMenu not clickable

Tags: android, slidingmenu

encountered such a problem. 
SlidingMenu use, and when I put forward, all that is in this menu is not active, not clickable. There is a simple test button, but when you push it happens absolutely nothing.

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/shadows_menu_swype2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="asdasd"/>

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/menu_swypeID"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/boder_menu_swype"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp">
</ListView>
```

SlidingMenu

```
menu = new SlidingMenu(this); // экземпляр класса
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT); 
        menu.setTouchModeBehind(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN); 
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadows_menu_swype1); 
        menu.setShadowWidth(15); 
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.50f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW); 
        menu.setBehindWidth(300);           
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_swype);
```

Grateful for any help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just changed `menu.setTouchModeBehind(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);`

to this, `menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);` and it worked. Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this:

```
    slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    slidingMenu.setTouchModeBehind(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
```

and removing:

```
    slidingMenu.setTouchModeBehind(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
```

resolved the problem.